# Vergangenheitsformen des Vorgangspassivs im Konjunktiv

Tags: subjunctive, passive, perfect-tense, past

Ich kann nicht verstehen, ob auch das Vorgangspassiv nur eine Konjunktiv-I- bzw. Konjunktiv-II-Form für das Perfekt, Präteritum und Plusquamperfekt hat (wie im Aktiv). Wenn ja (oder nein), wie sind sie gebildet?

Comment: Ich verstehe die Frage nicht: Wieso "nur eine Form"?

Comment: @chirlu: Siehe die Antworten: Zum Beispiel *sie ging* und *sie ist gegangen* (sowie *sie war gegangen,* je nachdem, wen man fragt) werden im Konjunktiv alle zu *sie sei gegangen* bzw. *sie wäre gegangen.*

Comment: Auch nach dem Edit von @Wrzlprmft ist mir die Frage noch ein Rätsel. Aber da du die Frage ja anscheinend verstanden hast, kannst du vielleicht noch mal die Frage überarbeiten, so dass das vielleicht mal Sinn ergibt?!

Comment: @Em1: Mir ist leider auch nicht klar, wie der Fragesteller auf die Idee kommt, dass ausgerechnet im Vorgangspassiv verschieden Konjunktiv-Formen für Perfekt und Präteritum existieren sollten. Deshalb wüsste ich leider nicht, wie ich die Frage klarer machen sollte.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Ahhh, also ist die Frage "Existiert im Vorgangspassiv eine andere K1 bzw. K2-Form für Perfekt, Präteritum und Pluquam als im Aktiv"?

Comment: @Em1: Ich sehe gerade, dass ich in meiner Änderung einen Fehler eingebaut habe. — Nein, die Frage ist gewissermaßen: »Existieren im Vorgangspassiv eine unterschiedliche K1- bzw. K2-Formen für Perfekt, Präteritum und Plusquamperfekt?«

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Das Vorgangspassiv wird in allen drei Vergangenheits-Zeiten genau gleich gebildet.

Ich stelle hier den Indikativ den beiden Konjuktiv-Formen gegenüber:

### Indikativ

Präsens, aktiv:

> Der Lehrer unterrichtet den Schüler.

Präsens, Vorgangspassiv, mit Agens:

> Der Schüler wird vom Lehrer unterrichtet.

Wie zuvor (Präsens, Vorgangspassiv), aber ohne Agens:

> Der Schüler wird unterrichtet.

Perfekt, Vorgangspassiv:

> Der Schüler ist unterrichtet worden.

Präteritum, Vorgangspassiv:

> Der Schüler wurde unterrichtet.

Plusquamperfekt, Vorgangspassiv:

> Der Schüler war unterrichtet worden.

### Konjunktiv I

Präsens, aktiv:

> Frau Maier sagt, der Lehrer unterrichte den Schüler.

Präsens, Vorgangspassiv, mit Agens:

> Frau Maier sagt, der Schüler werde vom Lehrer unterrichtet.

Wie zuvor (Präsens, Vorgangspassiv), aber ohne Agens:

> Frau Maier sagt, der Schüler werde unterrichtet.

Perfekt, Vorgangspassiv:

> Frau Maier sagt, der Schüler sei unterrichtet worden.

Präteritum, Vorgangspassiv:

> Frau Maier sagt, der Schüler sei unterrichtet worden.

Plusquamperfekt, Vorgangspassiv:

> Frau Maier sagt, der Schüler sei unterrichtet worden.

### Konjunktiv II

Präsens, aktiv:

> Der Lehrer würde den Schüler unterrichten (wenn nicht gerade Ferien wären).

Präsens, Vorgangspassiv, mit Agens:

> Der Schüler würde vom Lehrer unterrichtet werden.

Wie zuvor (Präsens, Vorgangspassiv), aber ohne Agens:

> Der Schüler würde unterrichtet werden.

Perfekt, Vorgangspassiv:

> Der Schüler wäre unterrichtet worden.

Präteritum, Vorgangspassiv:

> Der Schüler wäre unterrichtet worden.

Plusquamperfekt, Vorgangspassiv:

> Der Schüler wäre unterrichtet worden.

Answer (score 1):

Die Konjunktivbildung im Deutschen funktioniert grundsätzlich darüber, dass das konjugierte Verb durch die entsprechende zugehörige Konjunktivform ersetzt wird und alle dadurch auftretenden Partizipien ans Ende des Satzes geschoben werden:

Im Folgenden ist immer die Folge *Indikativ → Konjunktiv I → Konjunktiv II* angegeben:

1. Präsens von *sein:*

   > Er ist → Er sei → Er wäre
2. Präteritum/Perfekt von *sein* (beachte Parallele zu Punkt 1):

   > Er war / Er ist gewesen → Er sei gewesen → Er wäre gewesen
3. Präsens von *werden:*

   > Er wird → Er werde → Er würde
4. Präteritum/Perfekt von *werden* (beachte Parallele zu Punkt 1):

   > Er wurde / Er ist geworden → Er sei geworden → Er wäre geworden
5. Plusquamperfekt von *werden* (wende Punkt 2 auf *war* an):

   > Er war geworden → Er sei geworden gewesen → Er wäre geworden gewesen
6. Vorgangspassiv Präsens von *rufen* (wende Punkt 3 auf *wird* an):

   > Er wird gerufen → Er werde gerufen → Er würde gerufen
7. Vorgangspassiv Präteritum/Perfekt von *rufen* (wende Punkt 1 auf *ist* an bzw. Punkt 4 auf *wurde / ist […] worden*):

   > Er wurde gerufen / Er ist gerufen worden → Er sei gerufen worden → Er wäre gerufen worden

   Somit gibt es nur jeweils eine Konjunktiv-Form für Präteritum und Perfekt.
8. Vorgangspassiv Plusquamperfekt von *rufen* (wende Punkt 2 auf *war* an bzw. Punkt 5 auf *war […] worden*):

   > Er war gerufen worden → Er sei gerufen worden gewesen → Er wäre gerufen worden gewesen

Beachte, dass die Bildungen unter Punkt 5 und 8 als unschön, vermeidungswürdig oder gar nicht standardsprachlich angesehen werden und deshalb die entsprechenden Konjunktiv-Formen ganz vermieden werden, indem das Perfekt statt des Plusquamperfekts genutzt wird.